# How can I have margins or padding around a texture in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, textures

I am building a game using libgdx a 2048 like game and I draw the tiles of the board using textures (each texture represents a tile with the number 2 or 4 etc.)

I would like tohave a small space around the square textures. How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you give your actor (I suppose you use Scene2D) a bigger size, than your Image.

If you dont use Scene2D I recommend that you watch into it, because that would is the best way I can imagine to do such a game.

But as a final answer on your question: add transparency to your Image at the border. (which would go quite easy for once, but changing it would be a hell.

Or you try to use a Container. As example use Stack from Scene2D. You can place a bigger Image, which is transparent and on top of this Image a smaller one.
Now you can scale your padding, or your Image, as you want.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Stack.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply offset the texture's position by some amount? If you want a `5px` border around your images simply offset the position by `5` and the images will have a `5px` gap between them. Assuming an array of the textures you want to draw you could do something like this:

```
float prevPos = 0;
for (Texture tex : texturesToDraw) {
    // 5px to the right of the previous textures position
    float texturePos = prevPos + 5;
    float textureWidth = tex.getWidth();
    prevPos = texturePos + textureWidth;

    batch.draw(tex, texturePos, 0);
}
```